# generate unique link that runs an images slider with different images

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, angularjs

i searched all over the web and i couldn't find an answer, please help me!.

I have an HTML form, like this one:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="text" name="folder_name" placeholder="Folder name">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>
```

Now, upload.php takes number of images and store a link to the folder in MySQL.
Then i call query.php through angularJS $http to retrieve the link to the folder + the images.

Here is query.php:

```
session_start();
include 'connection.php';

header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

$folder = $_SESSION["target_folder"];
$query = "SELECT * FROM links WHERE link LIKE '%$folder%'";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();

$imagesArray = [];
$images = [];
$response = "";
$imageArray = "";
$first_response = "";

while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  $images = unserialize($row["images"]);
  $imagesArray = explode(",", $images);

  foreach($imagesArray as $image) {
    if ($response != "") {$response .= ",";}
    $response .= '{"target_folder":"'   . $row["link"]  . '",';
    //$response .= '"ext":"'                . $row["ext"]    . '",';
    $response .= '"billboardNumber":"'  . $image        . '"}';
  }
}
$response ='{"records":['.$response.']}';
echo $response;
```

Last is the slider in slider.html that retrieves the JSON data from query.php:

```
$http.get("php/query.php")  
  .success(function (response) {
    $scope.slides = response.records;
});
```

Most important part, my question :-)
every time i run slider.html it overwrites the old slider.html link and outputs the images from the last JSON call.
how can i run slider.html for a month and still get to the same folder even if i generate another 1000 links to different folder.
i hope that someone will understand me :-)
thank you !!!

Comment: Why don't you pass the required MySQL ID as a parameter to query.php. Something like : $http.get("php/query.php?id=$id") ?

Comment: first, thank you so much for your quick response, i already did it. but if i'll run slider.html after generating another link it will overwrite it.

Comment: normally when a specific link should be something like that:                                                        slider.html?a=djfhdjfhsdjfhsdhfjksdhfjksdhjfhsdjfd                                                                                                                         i'm not sure how it works in angularJS ??

Comment: My advice is to use ui-router. I'm not familiar with the "native" routing system provided by Angular (I'm not talking about the forthcoming new router : https://angular.github.io/router/), and ui-router is somewhat the de facto solution when working with Angular : https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#url-parameters.

Comment: if someone here know something about it please help with an example.